# Sum on distinct and group by

Tags: postgresql, sum

I have this :

```
CREATE TABLE tickets(id serial PRIMARY KEY, source text NOT NULL, user_id int NOT NULL, shop_id int NOT NULL, created_at time DEFAULT current_time);
INSERT INTO tickets VALUES (0, 'web-mobile', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO tickets VALUES (1, 'web-destkop', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO tickets VALUES (2, 'web-destkop', 2, 2);

SELECT shop_id, source, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) AS user_count
FROM tickets
WHERE shop_id = 2
GROUP BY shop_id, source;
```

Rexster : http://rextester.com/TDS9913

But what I would like is to get the sum of distinct `user_id` on `web-*`.

```
shop_id source  user_count
2       web     2
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. `count(distinct user_id)` is sufficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to group by a substring of source:

```
SELECT shop_id, 
       substring(source,1,3), 
       COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS user_count
FROM tickets
WHERE shop_id = 2
GROUP BY shop_id, substring(source,1,3);
```

http://rextester.com/EFZZSG27212

Comment: Is it possible to do the same but more declarative ? Like mentioning `'web-mobile' and 'web-desktop'` ? I tried using case statement but without success

Comment: @Mio: do you mean `where source in ('web-mobile', 'web-desktop')` instead of `where shop_id = 2`?

Comment: Sorry. Replace `substring` with something that mention `'web-mobile', 'web-desktop'`

Comment: If you're aggregating you have to "lose" some information!

Comment: I wrote an other related answer/question here : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190876/sum-on-distinct-and-group-by-and-filtering

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like:

```
SELECT   
  shop_id, 
  user_id,  
  COUNT(user_id)  AS user_count, 
  LEFT(source, 4) AS new_source
FROM tickets
GROUP BY (user_id, shop_id, new_source)
ORDER BY user_id;
```

Result: (check the db-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a71NU9MNLKrZKerGrZPe3o/4))

```
shop_id     user_id     user_count  new_source
      2           1              2        web-
      2           2              1        web-
```

Of course you can use `SUBSTRING` instead of `LEFT` as suggested.