# Sum on distinct and group by and filtering

Tags: postgresql

This is the next version of [Sum on distinct and group by](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190866/sum-on-distinct-and-group-by)

But It goes deeper

I have this :

```
CREATE TABLE active_connections(id serial PRIMARY KEY, source text NOT NULL, user_id int NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (0, 'web-mobile', 1);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (1, 'web-desktop', 1);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (2, 'web-desktop', 2);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (3, 'web-desktop', 3);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (4, 'web-desktop', 3);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (5, 'native', 3);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (6, 'native', 4);
```

What I'm trying to do is to group distinct user per `native` vs `'web-desktop'` and `'web-mobile'`.

I would like to get

```
source  user_count
native  2
web     3
```

I'm able to do it only if I alias the `source` column to something different. I don't understand why

```
SELECT 
CASE
  WHEN source IN ('web-mobile', 'web-desktop') THEN 'web'
  ELSE source
  END AS source_2,
COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS user_count
FROM active_connections
GROUP BY source_2;
```

First why I can say `END AS source`? Second can I do it without using a subquery like below to be able to have `source` column?

```
WITH mapped_source AS ( SELECT 
CASE
  WHEN source IN ('web-mobile', 'web-desktop') THEN 'web'
  ELSE source
  END AS web_or_native,
COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) AS user_count
FROM active_connections
GROUP BY web_or_native )

SELECT web_or_native AS source, user_count FROM mapped_source;
```

Rextester : http://rextester.com/FRB66163

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY 1` (meaning "group by the 1st column") but this is going to be deprecated in future versions. And I want to stress - one more time - that `DISTINCT` is not a function – https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993

You can avoid the sub-query (or CTE) if you are willing to repeat the `CASE` statement in the `GROUP BY` - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822

```
CREATE TABLE active_connections(id serial PRIMARY KEY, source text NOT NULL, user_id int NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (0, 'web-mobile', 1);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (1, 'web-desktop', 1);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (2, 'web-desktop', 2);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (3, 'web-desktop', 3);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (4, 'web-desktop', 3);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (5, 'native', 3);
INSERT INTO active_connections VALUES (6, 'native', 4);

SELECT CASE
         WHEN source IN ('web-mobile', 'web-desktop') THEN 'web'
         ELSE source
       END AS source,
       COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS user_count
FROM active_connections
GROUP BY CASE
         WHEN source IN ('web-mobile', 'web-desktop') THEN 'web'
         ELSE source
       END;
```